# Regular expression for number with length of 4, 5 or 6

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression that validate for a number with length 4, 5, 6

I used `^[0-9]{4}` to validate for a number of 4, but I do not know how to include validation for 5 and 6.

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem, please add it as an answer

Comment: You should always specify the language you are using your regexes from. While for simple regexes it couldn't be important, more complex ones depend on the starting language. It's even written in the tag.

Comment: GHYATH!! shou hal Q? shou d3eef!

Comment: what if i need it for exactly 4 or 6 digits

Comment: in case you're looking to find the number anywhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328875/javascript-regex-to-remove-all-numbers-with-specific-lenght-or-do-a-persistent

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[0-9]{4,6}$
```

`{4,6}` = between 4 and 6 characters, inclusive.

Comment: Hi, i need to validate only  length of either 4 or 6. How can i achieve this. If user gives length of 5 numbers. It should give error wrt to pattern. Please help

Comment: @Hema Please use ^(\d{4}|\d{6})?$ regex to validate number either 4 or 6 length. It will give success only if you enter digits length of 4 or 6

Answer (score 19):

`[0-9]{4,6}` can be shortened to `\d{4,6}`

Answer (score 14):

Be aware that, as written, Peter's solution will "accept" `0000`. If you want to validate numbers between `1000` and `999999`, then that is another problem :-)

```
^[1-9][0-9]{3,5}$
```

for example will block inserting `0` at the beginning of the string.

If you want to accept 0 padding, but only up to a lengh of 6, so that `001000` is valid, then it becomes more complex. If we use look-ahead then we can write something like

```
^(?=[0-9]{4,6}$)0*[1-9][0-9]{3,}$
```

This first checks if the string is long 4-6 `(?=[0-9]{4,6}$)`, then skips the 0s `0*`and search for a non-zero `[1-9]` followed by at least 3 digits `[0-9]{3,}`.

Comment: Regarding your second regex: `^(?=[0-9]{4,6}$)0*[1-9][0-9]{3,}$` - The `{3,}` erroneously requires three digits past the first `[1-9]`, and thus it will fail to match numbers such as: `000001` and `0123`. Since your lookahead already ensures the length requirement, the `{3,}` can be written as just a `*` star. (Or is this the behavior you intended?)

Comment: @ridgerunner As I have written, the minimum number is 1000, so 1-9 and three free digits. So it is correct. These regexes try to check the value and not only the syntax.

Answer (score 4):

To match standalone 4-6-digit numbers, you may use

```
^\d{4,6}$             // If full string match is expected
\b\d{4,6}\b           // If no letters/digits/underscores are expected on both ends
(?<!\d)\d{4,6}(?!\d)  // If no digits are expected on both ends, but letters/_ are allowed
(^|\D)(\d{4,6})(?!\d) // Same as above, in case lookbehinds are not supported (get Group 2 value)
```

See [Regex #1](https://regex101.com/r/S6oyIH/1) - [Regex #2](https://regex101.com/r/S6oyIH/2) - [Regex #3](https://regex101.com/r/S6oyIH/3) and [Regex #4](https://regex101.com/r/S6oyIH/4) demos.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `\b` - a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `(?<!\d)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a digit immediately to the left of the current location
- `(^|\D)` - a capturing group matching either start of string or a non-digit char
- `\d{4,6}` - four, five or six digits
- `(?!\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a digit immediately to the right of the current location
- `$` - end of string

Answer (score 3):

If the language you use accepts `{}`, you can use `[0-9]{4,6}`.

If not, you'll have to use `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?`.