# Remove a 4- to 6-digit number from an alphanumeric string

Tags: regex, string, coldfusion

In ColdFusion, I am trying to match and remove 4 to 6 consecutive digits from a string. The string looks something like this:

`ABC1234DEFGH` or `ABCDEF123456`

The string is limited to 20 characters and will only contain numbers and letters. The digits are always consecutive and can occur anywhere after the first character of the string. There will only be one occurrence of consecutive digits. If there are fewer than 4 or greater than 6 digits, I want to keep them.

So, for example, if I have a string like this:

```
ABC1234DEFGH
```

The desired result will be `ABCDEFGH`.

For this string:

```
A123BCDEFGH
```

The desired result will be `A123BCDEFGH`.

For this string:

```
ABCDE1234567FG
```

The desired result is `ABCDE1234567FG`.

I tried the suggestion in this post : [Regular expression for number with length of 4, 5 or 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864971/regular-expression-for-number-with-length-of-4-5-or-6) but it doesn't  quite cover my requirements.

The suggestion is: `[0-9]{4,6}`

This expression will remove ANY string with 4 to 6 digits, so if the string has 7 digits, it will remove 6 of them, but I want to keep all 7 digits.  I don't know how to create a regular expression that will ONLY match strings of exactly 4, 5, or 6 consecutive digits.

I will greatly appreciate any and all help. (Thanks to ifm for the formatting edit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 ([^\d])[0-9]{4,6}([^\d])
```

This should do it for you.See demo.Replace by `\1\2`

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/124

Comment: what about `12534`? ;)

Comment: Thanks for your response. That code produces a ColdFusion error, I'm afraid. But I am grateful for the detail in your code example. It's very informative.

Comment: @vks It looks the same to me.

Comment: @vks, Oh, I see, the text in the answer above is different. But when I go to the demo, it still shows this: (?<!\d)[0-9]{4,6}(?!\d).

I tried your edited version:([^\d])[0-9]{4,6}([^\d])

and when I put in ABC123456DEFG, I get back ABEFG

Comment: @geh you have to replace by `$1$2`.see demo

Comment: @vks Perfect! With one tiny little change: in ColdFusion, the back reference is denoted by \n, rather than $n, so the $1$2 must be written as \1\2. Thank you!

Comment: @geh just click the green tick or the thicker arrow :)

Comment: Just FYI, ColdFusion regular expressions don't have lookbehind (they do have lookahead). If you need to use lookbehind in CF, you can use Java regex.

Answer (score 4):

I think this will do the job:

```
(\A|[^0-9])([0-9]{4,6})([^0-9]|$)
```

It seeks for a sequence of 4 to 6 digits, between 2 non-digit characters or string delimiters (beginning/end).

Comment: Wow! Thank you for answering so quickly. I tried your expression, and it does keep 3 or fewer and 7 or more digits. But for 4, 5, or 6 digits, it removes  the last alpha character before the numbers, and one alpha character after the numbers, regardless of the position of the numbers. For example, ABCDE123456 becomes ABCD, and ABC1234DE becomes ABE.

Comment: @Kasra it will be removed

Comment: @Kasra `The digits are always consecutive and can occur anywhere after the first character of the string. There will only be one occurrence of consecutive digits` dat case is invalid

Comment: @Kasra Mouseover on the upvote says "This answer is useful." It doesn't say "This answer is correct." I thought the answer was useful (helpful) even though it wasn't 100% correct. Part of it WAS correct. So I upvoted it.

Comment: I've been playing with @vks's answer on that regex101.com site, and after a while I realized that your answer actually does work, if the substitution is \1\3 or $1$3. So the solution can be done either this way:

(\A|[^0-9])([0-9]{4,6})([^0-9]|$) (substituting $1$3)

or this way:

 ([^\d])[0-9]{4,6}([^\d]|$) (substituting $1$2)

Your answer had the "|$" in the last group, which turned out to be necessary. 

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
<cfset mystring = REReplace(mystring, "(\D)\d{4,6}(?=\D)" , "\1") />
```

[**Regex 101 Demo here.**](https://regex101.com/r/lV3wX8/2)

The regex captures a non-digit character `\D` and put it into capture group 1. It then searches for 4 to 6 digits that are followed by something a non-digit.